# Two setContentVIew for XML and Custom View

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Is it possible to have a `2 setContentView`? because I have already my `Custom View` which draw my game and also I want to have a countdown timer for it but the tutorial that I have on this timer is created on `XML layout`. Is it possible? I had search on web but I it seems that I cant find the right answer on my problem.

Thanks for any suggestions/ help.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want to include one Layout inside of another? This is possible via the <include..> Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You may open a Dialog and set it Cancelable (False) so dialog will not be cancelled also set property clickableOutside(true) so you can click out of DIalog Now just set the dialog where you want and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try inflating the other layout.